How to best install cross beams instead of loft legs
I need to board my loft, and maintain the recommended 270mm of insulation depth.
The existing joists are 4x2" (giving 100mm depth) so I'm looking at adding the additional 170mm with either plastic "loft legs" or 7x2" wooden cross beams.
Cost and ease of installation aren't a huge factor (although the superior plastic systems with metal cross beams are expensive). Mainly I'm concerned about load on the original joists.
I'd be happier with wood, if practical. However, I'm concerned about the additional weight of wooden beams and want to avoid the joists bearing the full weight, as they would be with legs. However, there's no brick wall in the loft to hang the beams from.
The original joists would be taking most of the weight, but in my picture below you can see to the far side there is a 7" joist. This deeper joist runs down the other side too. I'm wondering if they are on top of exterior brick walls, and also whether I can make use of the angled rafters for support.

Would you suggest installing wooden beams? How would you secure them to minimise load on the joists? Or do you think it would be safer/better to install lighter loft legs instead?

I presume these additional beams would run right to left in the pic, parallel to the upper one near the 8" marking. How far is the unsupported span from left to right? There's a load bearing wall (running L-to-R) near the front of the pic where the joist ends overlap, are there any additional load bearing walls that may run front-to-back in this pic that would help support the weight?

You might be able to run one joist L-R above the load bearing wall (carefully avoiding all the wiring), then run your new joists front to back suspending them by their ends in joist hangers off of the newly added joist and the one at the back with the 8" label. If the goal is to break thermal bridging, offset the new joists from the old ones by a 1/2 bay (also allowing for wiring to dip over/under).

Good point about the load bearing wall by the over-lapping beams.
The full span is 4 metres L-R. And the distance from the load bearing wall at the front is about 5 metres to the far end.
The 8" high cross beam near the back isn't above a load bearing wall, but presumably is putting its weight on the side wall. So should that be safe to hang from? The end wall is a couple of metres further back into the gable, and is above a bay window.

Ah, those dimensions weren't obvious from the pic. I'd estimate that NO that mid-point beam at the 8" label is not sufficient for hanging joists from. You'd need to go look up span tables for code compliance at your locale to see how tall it would have to be to have additional joists hung off both sides to safely support the weight at the ends without sagging (and destroying the plaster & lath ceiling) in the middle.

Looks like the 7x3" beam to the right is not above a brick wall, but both its ends are. The unsupported span between those two walls being 14'. Do you think there's a configuration where cross beams are distributing their weight on the existing 2x4s, while letting the 7x3 take some of the strain? It only protrudes +3" from the lower beam level.

The ultra-conservative "I'm some guy on the internet looking at one picture" answer is NO you can't do what you're asking. I don't want to be the reason your ceiling collapses. Get quotes from a couple of local builders who will actually go up into your attic and take a look. Ask for detailed quotes - they'll write up what they'd do in terms of structuring it to support the weight you're expecting. You don't have to accept the quotes & hire them, but you'll have an idea of what's involved to do it safely. Or, as your local building inspector to take a look.
